# Разделители в Navigation View

Tags: android, android-menu, android-xml, android-navigation-view

Нужно сделать следующие разделители, как на скрине:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Под цифрой 1 от логотипа красной чертой.

Под цифрой 2 между "Settings" и "Rate app".

Если на счет первого пункта я даже примерно не знаю, как это сделать - то со вторым пробовал следующую разметку:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/recent_activity"
            android:title="Your recent activity" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/recent_suggestion"
            android:title="Recent suggestion" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/suggest_term_drawer"
            android:title="Suggest term" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/settings"
            android:title="Settings" />

        <item android:title=""></item>
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/rate_app"
                android:title="Rate app" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/feedback"
                android:title="Feedback" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/share"
                android:icon="@drawable/share"
                android:title="Share" />
        </menu>

    </group>

</menu>
```

Однако выходило так, что от разделителя были расстояния снизу и сверху примерно в 1 итем.

Вот разметка логотипа:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_menu"/>
```

Comment: Вот тут решение: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30605906/5698593

Comment: @iFr0z спасибо, не могли бы насчет логотипа ответить - и оформить как ответ?

Comment: ответил, должно помочь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создать **navigation_header.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"> //можно и свое расстояние задать

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_menu"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

В разметке `NavigationView` добавьте `app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:itemIconTint="#2196F3"
        app:itemTextColor="#2196F3"
        ...
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_items"/>
```

В `Activity`, где находится `NavigationView` добавить еще:

```
View headerView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.navigation_header, navigation, false);
if (navigation != null) navigation.addHeaderView(headerView); 
ImageView logo = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
```

А с отступами решение [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605286/navigationview-insert-divider-without-subgroup/30605906#30605906)

Comment: не находит метод `addHeaderView()`

Comment: @Asgard `NavigationView navigation` используете? екмакарек. Забыл сказать в разметке `NavigationView` добавьте `app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"` Я дико извиняюсь! Исправил ответ. Теперь точно должно работать!

Comment: @Asgard больше проблем нет? помогло?)

Comment: прошу прощения за игнор, положили в больницу и только что вернулся.Как только что-то буду делать, о результате напишу, спасибо

Comment: @Asgard хорошо:)

Comment: не получается с лого, он их две картинки вставляет - а полоски не делает.